# Looping through Adjacent Cells Under a Merged Cell

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to create a VBA code that will let me refer to a header that is merged and go through all the cells that are under the header. Is it possible to create a Do Until Loop that goes through a range of adjacent merged cells?

For example, the header is a merged cell from A1 to C1 and D1 to G1 and I want to create a loop that counts values from different sources under each header.
Currently, I have a for loop which goes through the specific column numbers but I am thinking of changing it to a Do Until Loop so when I add a column and include it in the header and re-run the macro, it will include all columns under the header.

```
'Signals (Ped)
For a = 143 To 148
    For b = 4 To 203
    Worksheets("EACH ITEM CALCS").Cells(b, a).Value = _
        Application.CountIfs(Range(Worksheets("SIGNAL POLE SCHED WORKSHEET").Cells(9, 25), Worksheets("SIGNAL POLE SCHED WORKSHEET").Cells(5000, 25)), Worksheets("EACH ITEM CALCS").Cells(b, 1), _
        Range(Worksheets("SIGNAL POLE SCHED WORKSHEET").Cells(9, 46), Worksheets("SIGNAL POLE SCHED WORKSHEET").Cells(5000, 46)), Worksheets("EACH ITEM CALCS").Cells(3, a), _
        Range(Worksheets("SIGNAL POLE SCHED WORKSHEET").Cells(9, 44), Worksheets("SIGNAL POLE SCHED WORKSHEET").Cells(5000, 44)), "<>X")
Next b
Next a

'Ped Button
For b = 4 To 203
Worksheets("EACH ITEM CALCS").Cells(b, 149).Value = _
    Application.CountIfs(Range(Worksheets("SIGNAL POLE SCHED WORKSHEET").Cells(9, 25), Worksheets("SIGNAL POLE SCHED WORKSHEET").Cells(5000, 25)), Worksheets("EACH ITEM CALCS").Cells(b, 1), _
    Range(Worksheets("SIGNAL POLE SCHED WORKSHEET").Cells(9, 49), Worksheets("SIGNAL POLE SCHED WORKSHEET").Cells(5000, 49)), "<>-", _
    Range(Worksheets("SIGNAL POLE SCHED WORKSHEET").Cells(9, 48), Worksheets("SIGNAL POLE SCHED WORKSHEET").Cells(5000, 48)), "<>X")
Next b
```

[These are the headers an cells that I want to reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Raxx.png)
Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.mergearea might be useful.

Comment: Always helps to include your existing code, even if it doesn't quite do what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know about using `Do Until`, but if you just need to find the Range of used cells underneath a merged header, you can use `Range.MergeArea`, which returns the collection of cells that are merged together for the given range. And then `EntireColumn` to get the full columns of that merged area. Then you just need to trim it down to the non-blank region and cut off the top part where the header is.

Here's an example of how to get this range.

```vb
Sub Example()
    Debug.Print UsedAreaUnderMergedHeader(Range("A1:C1")).Address
    Debug.Print UsedAreaUnderMergedHeader(Range("A1")).Address
    'My header is merged "A1:C1"
    'Both lines print the same output
    'Output is "$A$2:$C$28"
End Sub

Function UsedAreaUnderMergedHeader(Header As Range) As Range
    'Finding the Merged Area of the Header
    Dim MergedArea As Range
    Set MergedArea = Header.Cells(1).MergeArea
    
    'Finding the set of columns for that merged area
    Dim WholeColumns As Range
    Set WholeColumns = MergedArea.Columns.EntireColumn
    
    'Find the last row in the set of columns (check each column)
    Dim Column As Range, LastRow As Long
    For Each Column In WholeColumns.Columns
        Dim cLast As Long
        cLast = Column.Cells(Header.Parent.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        If cLast > LastRow Then LastRow = cLast
    Next
    
    'Build and return the range - The area under the merged header, up till the last row
    Set UsedAreaUnderMergedHeader = Header.Offset(MergedArea.Rows.Count).Resize(LastRow - MergedArea.Row - MergedArea.Rows.Count + 1, WholeColumns.Columns.Count)
End Function
```

Then you can loop through this range like

```vb
Dim Cell As Range
For Each Cell In MyRange.Cells
   'do stuff
Next
```

Or you can loop by rows like

```vb
Dim Row As Range
For Each Row in MyRange.Rows
   'do stuff
Next
```

Comment: @BigBen I always appreciate learning new things like this. Thank you! I will update my answer to make use of this advice.